# Precision of Floats to Ints vs Doubles to Ints, unexpected results

Tags: c++, casting

I am computer engineering student and do tutoring for the introductory C++ classes at BYU-Idaho, and a student successfully stumped me.

If write the code for this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   float y = .59;
   int x = (int)(y * 100.0);
   cout << x << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Result = 58

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   double y = .59;
   int x = (int)(y * 100.0);
   cout << x << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Result = 59

I told him it was a precision issue and that because the int is more precise than a float it loses information. A double is more precise than a float so it works.

However I am not sure if what I said is correct. I think it has something to do with the int getting padded with zeros and as a result it gets "truncated" while it get's casted, but I am not sure.

If any of you guys want to explain what is going on "underneath" all of this I would find it interesting!

Comment: All you need to know is that floating point types are not exact (so `y * 100.0` is not actually 59), and converting a floating point value to an integral value works by truncating.

Comment: By the way, is your university OK with you posting your affiliation here? :-)

Comment: Also see this [faq](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/floating-point-arith.html) for more details and further reading.

Comment: I think so, I guess I didn't worry too much about it, I am just proud of my school =)

Comment: Not sure I agree with the FAQ here.  The recommendation to never use `==` is certainly wrong.

Comment: Why would the University not be OK with it?

Comment: [This is a good read](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `float` isn't accurate enough to hold the *exact* value 0.59. If you store such a value, it will be rounded in binary representation (already during compile time) to something different, in your case this was a value slightly less than 0.59 (it might also be slightly greater than the value you wanted it to be). When multiplying this with 100, you get a value slightly less than 59. Converting such a value to an integer will round it *towards 0*, so this leads to 58.

0.59 as a float will be stored as (now being represented as a human-readable decimal number):

```
0.589999973773956298828125
```

Now to the `double` type. While this type has essentially the same problem, it might be of two reasons why you get the expected result: Either `double` can hold the *exact* value you want (this is not the case with 0.59 but for other values it might be the case), or the compiler decides to round it *up*. Thus, multiplying this with 100 leads to a value which is *not* less than 59 and will be rounded towards 0 to 59, as expected.

Now note that it might be the case that 0.59 as a `double` is still being rounded down by the compiler. Indeed, I just checked and it is. 0.59 as a `double` will be stored as:

```
0.58999999999999996891375531049561686813831329345703
```

However, you are multiplying this value with 100 *before* converting it to an integer. Now there comes an interesting point: When multiplied with 100, the difference of `y` to 0.59 put by the compiler is *eliminated* since 0.59 * 100 can again not be stored exactly. In fact, the processor calculates `0.58999999999999996891375531049561686813831329345703 * 100.0`, which will be rounded *up* to 59, a number which *can* be represented in `double`!

See this code for details: http://ideone.com/V0essb

Now you might wonder why the same doesn't count for `float`, which should behave exactly the same but with different accuracy. The problem is that `0.589999973773956298828125 * 100.0` is *not* rounded up to `59` (which can also be represented in a `float`). The rounding behavior after calculations isn't really defined.

Indeed, operations on floating point numbers aren't exactly specified, meaning that you can encounter different results on different machines. This makes it possible to implement performance tweaks which lead to slightly incorrect results, *even if rounding isn't involved*! It might be the case that on another machine you end up with the expected results while on others you are not.

Comment: The conversion to `int` doesn't round down, it truncates to 0.

Comment: Is the last paragraph really true (provided we're talking about an IEEE 754 compliant implementation)?

Comment: @NPE He said on different machines.  Which is exactly the point; not all machines use IEEE.

Comment: @njfife I updated my answer, please also see the code and its output I linked.

Comment: @leemes Looks great, I hope this helps others with the same question later!

Answer (score 2):

0.59 is not exactly representable in binary floating-point.  So `x` will actually be a value very slightly above or below 0.59.  Which it is may be affected by whether you use `float` or `double`.  This in turn will determine whether the result of your program is 58 or 59.

Comment: If you look at the actual `float` and `double` values, you'll see that they both are *below* `59`. Therefore I am afraid the current explanation is not sufficient.

Comment: @NPE: Don't be fooled by the fact that the OP is initializing the `float` from a `double` literal.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I am not. I've compiled and run the program, and have looked at the actual values.

Comment: @NPE Strangly enough, I'm seeing the same thing.  I wonder if the compiler is doing some illegal optimizations here, however, because when I do `100. * y - 59.`, I get exactly  the same value, regardless of the type of `y`.  Which would mean that `.59` has exactly the same value as a `float` and as a `double`, which isn't possible.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Have you tried various "precise" float compiler options? GCC has several of those I think...

Answer (score 2):

It is a precision issue, and has to do with the fact that `.59`
is not exactly representable in either a `double` or a `float`.
So `y` is *not* `.59`; it is something very close to `.59`
(slightly more or slightly less).  The multiplication by `100`
is exact, but since the original value wasn't, you get something
slightly more or slightly less than `59`.  Conversion to `int`
truncates to zero, so you get either `59` or `58`.

Comment: What do you mean by "the multiplication by `100` is exact"?  In general for `double x;` the represented value of `100*x` is not always exactly 100 times the represented value of `x`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same problem as when you use an old calculator to do `1 / 3 * 3`, and it comes up with `2.9999999` or something similar. Combine this with the fact that the `(int)(float_value)` will simply chop the decimals of, so if `floatvalue` is `58.999996185` like my machine gets, then `58` will be the result, because although `58.999996185` is NEARLY 59, if you cut out only the first two digits, it is indeed 58.

Floating point numbers are great for calculating a lot of things, but you have to be VERY careful when it comes to "what is the result". It is an approximation, the precision is not infinite, and rounding of intermediate results will happen.

With double, there are more digits, and it may well be that when the calculation of 0.58999999999999 times 100, the last bit is a one instead of a zero, so the result is a 59.00000000001 or something like that, whcih then becomes 59 as an integer.